# Find out FILESTREAM share name in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, filestream

Real quick question - I must be blind or something.

In SQL Server Mgmt Studio, I can check for the level of filestream support currently enabled by

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level
```

Great, works. But how can I find the Windows share name specified during installation where the filestream data will actually be stored? I can't seem to find any settings, configuration option or anything to do that. Can this be?? I can't find this out??

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following query:
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('FILESTREAMShareName')

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can retrieve the Filestream support level without using sp_configure with the below option.

```
select SERVERPROPERTY(N'FilestreamConfiguredLevel')
```